# Spring JPA - "Invalid column index" when inserting in DB

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I am facing an issue when trying to insert 1 record in a parent table (**DART_ORDER**) and 2 records in a child table connected to the parent (**DART_ODATE**). Those 2 tables are linked by a OneToMany-ManyToOne relation as follows:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Entity
@Table(
    name = "DART_ORDER",
    schema = Constants.ORACLE_DB_SCHEMA
)
public class OrderDAO implements Serializable {

  @NotNull
  private String WHY;

  @NotNull
  private String WHO;

  @Id
  @NotNull
  private String ORDERID;

  private String DESCRIPTION;

  @NotNull
  private String STATUS;

  @NotNull
  private String COUNTRY;

  @NotNull
  private String TYPE;

  @NotNull
  private String REPETITION;

  private String REF_REFORDERID;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ORDER", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @OrderBy("DID ASC")
  @ToString.Exclude
  private List<OrderDateDAO> DATES;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ORDER", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @OrderBy("DID ASC")
  @ToString.Exclude
  private List<OrderDocDAO> DOCS;

}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Entity
@Table(
    name = "DART_ODATE",
    schema = Constants.ORACLE_DB_SCHEMA,
    indexes = @Index(
        name = "PK_DART_ODATE",
        columnList = "REF_ORDERID, ODTTYPE",
        unique = true
    )
)
@IdClass(OrderDateDAO.class)
public class OrderDateDAO implements Serializable {

  @NotNull
  private String WHY;

  @NotNull
  private String WHO;

  @Id
  @NotNull
  private String REF_ORDERID;

  @Id
  @NotNull
  private String ODTTYPE;

  @NotNull
  private LocalDate ODATE;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "REF_ORDERID", referencedColumnName = "ORDERID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  @ToString.Exclude
  private OrderDAO ORDER;

}
```

When I try saving a record giving a complete *OrderDAO* object, I get the following exception:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setFormOfUseInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10470)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setFormOfUseInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10451)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setString(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5240)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setString(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:255)
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.setString(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
> at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:46)
> at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:73)
> at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:276)
> at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:271)
> at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeSet(ComponentType.java:340)
> at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrateId(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3121)
> at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3079)
> at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3372)
> ... 87 more

By enabling the logs for Hibernate's SQL statements, I noticed that the insert one for the *DART_ODATE* table has the correct number of *?* symbols as parameters, but, for no apparent reason, the log immediately below shows **7 parameters passed, instead of 6**, among which 1 seems to be *null*.

> 2022-05-03T13:27:24,074 TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder: binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [null]

I don't honestly know why it keeps considering 1 parameter in addition, since the only additional mapping set in the DAO is the *JoinColumn* one...
Besides, I already tried upgrading both my SpringBoot and Hibernate Validator versions to the latest ones, but I still got the error.

Has any of you experienced the same issue?

Thank you.

Regards,
A.M.

Comment: Maybe an issue with `private List<OrderDocDAO> DOCS;`

Comment: Hi! Why is that? That parameter could be null, since no DOCS could be lined to the parent DAO. Besides, looking a the logs, the error is encountered when the first INSERT statement for DART_ODATE is processed.

Comment: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not insert: [eu.unicredit.dtm.dtm_be.dao.oracle.OrderDateDAO]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [eu.unicredit.dtm.dtm_be.dao.oracle.OrderDateDAO]

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to understand my mistake!

The issue was related to a wrong use of the *JoinColumn* annotation.
Basically, I removed the **ORDER** attribute within the *OrderDateDAO", and changed the parent **DATES** attribute as follows:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "REF_ORDERID", referencedColumnName = "ORDERID")
@ToString.Exclude
private List<OrderDateDAO> DATES;
```

Using a uni-directional relation, the INSERT statement worked like a charm! :-)